# YouTube API Quota quick overflow

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to create a simple **YouTube API** request and quickly get **403** response code (*Quota limit*). According to [YouTube API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started), the default quota is 10000 units per day. According to the [same docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), my request costs **3-5** units. However, I can get no more than 100 requests per day.

Here is a script that I wrote which consequently does the same requests:

```
key=<My Youtube API key>
request="https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?type=video&part=id,snippet&order=relevance&maxResults=10&key=$key&q=hello"

for i in {0..1000}
 do
    echo "Try #$i"
    response=`curl -i $request | grep HTTP/2 | awk '{print $2}'`

    if [ $response == 403 ]
    then
      break
    fi
    echo $response
 done

echo "$i tries succeeded"
```

It gives

`97 tries succeeded`

In Google console I see that my script consumed almost all 10000 units

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs' [quota calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost), the cost of one invocation of Search endpoint is not 3-5 units, but **100** units. (This fact is also mentioned on Search endpoint's [doc page itself](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list).) This explains that upon 100 calls to that endpoint your daily quota of 10000 units gets exhausted.